# Connect DB with Azure MFA from visual studio to compare project solution against Azure DB?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, azure, azure-sql-database, visual-studio-extensions

I am trying to compare my database project (.sln) with a Azure DB which can be connected using Azure MFA option. I can compare DB vs DB with SSMS and DB/bacpac vs DB/bacpac (Azure Data Studio+Schema compare extn.). Is there any way to connect it from visual studio to compare .sln(DB Project Solution) vs DB? Any VS extensions ?

SSMS - Working Fine

[image: SSMS - Working Fine]

From Visual Studio 2017 Server Explorer - No option
[image: From Visual Studio 2017 Server Explorer - No option]

Comment: Hi Rahul Chowdhury, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: did you get any progress now?

Answer (score 2):

SSMS and SqlPackage.exe are the only tools currently enabled for MFA through Active Directory Universal Authentication.

Please ref: [Universal Authentication limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-mfa-ssms-overview#universal-authentication-limitations)

Hope this helps.